# Smooth tableview scrolling with multiple label and a webview in each cell?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

How to make tableview scroll smooth...I am inserting 8 label and a webview in each cell of tableview 
due to this tableview scrolling is not smooth... 
below is my code

```
{
    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        arr =[appDelegate.recentlyaddedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *cellValue = [arr objectForKey: @"title"]; 
    #if USE_CUSTOM_DRAWING
        const NSInteger TOP_LABEL_TAG = 1001;

        UILabel *topLabel;


#endif

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectZero  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    cell.accessoryView =[[[UIImageView alloc]  initWithImage:indicatorImage] autorelease];


#if USE_CUSTOM_DRAWING


    const CGFloat LABEL_HEIGHT =100;
    arr =[appDelegate.recentlyaddedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    appDelegate.totalComments=[arr objectForKey:@"totalComments"];
    appDelegate.totalViews=[arr objectForKey: @"totalViews"];
    appDelegate.totalVotes=[arr objectForKey: @"totalVotes"];
    appDelegate.textfield=[arr objectForKey: @"title"];
    appDelegate.mytextview=[arr objectForKey: @"verse"];
    appDelegate.userid=[arr objectForKey: @"user_id"];
    appDelegate.added_date=[arr objectForKey: @"addedDate"];
    appDelegate.username=[arr objectForKey:@"user_name"];
    appDelegate.profilepic=[arr objectForKey:@"profile_pic"];
    NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.profilepic);





    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,80 ,80 );
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    webView.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;   
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    webView.opaque=NO;
    NSString *htmlTempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"%@\" width=50 height=60 /></body></html>",appDelegate.profilepic];
    NSString *htmlTempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n %@\n\n\n\n Votes(%@) Views(%@) Comments(%@)",cellValue,appDelegate.added_date,appDelegate.totalVotes,appDelegate.totalViews,appDelegate.totalComments];      
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlTempString baseURL:nil];
[cell.contentView addSubview:webView];
    [webView release];  







    topLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(70,0,240,LABEL_HEIGHT)] autorelease];
    [topLabel setNumberOfLines:-1];




    UILabel *Titlelable = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(57,4,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Titlelable];
    Titlelable.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    Titlelable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Titlelable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    Titlelable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
    Titlelable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n%@\n",cellValue];



    UILabel *usernamelabel = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(68,20,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:usernamelabel];
    usernamelabel.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    usernamelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    usernamelabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    usernamelabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10];
    usernamelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nBy %@\n",appDelegate.username];





    UILabel *Timelabel = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(57,40,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Timelabel];
    Timelabel.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    Timelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Timelabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    Timelabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    Timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n%@\n",appDelegate.added_date];




    UILabel *votelable = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(101,56,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:votelable];
    votelable.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    votelable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    votelable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    votelable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    votelable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n",appDelegate.totalVotes];




    UILabel *viewlable = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(155,56,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:viewlable];
    viewlable.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    viewlable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    viewlable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewlable.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    viewlable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n\n",appDelegate.totalViews];




    UILabel *commentlabel = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(235,56,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:commentlabel];
    commentlabel.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    commentlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    commentlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    commentlabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    commentlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n%@\n",appDelegate.totalComments];





    [cell.contentView addSubview:topLabel];
    topLabel.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    topLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    topLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    topLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];

    UIImage *cellBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];
    cell.backgroundView =[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellBack] autorelease];
    topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Votes(   ) Views(    ) Comments(   )"];
//  topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n\n\n\n Votes(%@) Views(%@) Comments(%@)",appDelegate.added_date,appDelegate.totalVotes,appDelegate.totalViews,appDelegate.totalComments];
//  topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n %@\n\n\n\n Votes(%@) Views(%@) Comments(%@)",cellValue,appDelegate.added_date,appDelegate.totalVotes,appDelegate.totalViews,appDelegate.totalComments]; 
#else
    cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell at row %ld.", [indexPath row]];



#endif

    return cell;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to offend you but you should get more practice with basic topics.

For example this code:

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arr =[appDelegate.recentlyaddedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

produces a leak, because you assign a new object to a variable holding an object without releasing the old one.

This code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectZero  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

is useless, because you do basically the same like in the first snippet. You don't reuse your cells, that's why your scrolling isn't smooth.

Change it to something like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectZero  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // everything else
    // example:

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(57,4,240,20)] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
    titleLabel.tag = TOP_LABEL_TAG;
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];

}
// set values
// example:
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TOP_LABEL_TAG];
titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n%@\n",cellValue];
```

Instead of `// everything else` you put all your calls that add new views to the cell.

Instead of `// set values` you use the tags you set earlier to change the attributes of the views you have added.

Et voila, smooth scrolling.

If you've done this you should get rid of that useless monster:

```
const CGFloat LABEL_HEIGHT =100;
arr =[appDelegate.recentlyaddedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
appDelegate.totalComments=[arr objectForKey:@"totalComments"];
/../
appDelegate.profilepic=[arr objectForKey:@"profile_pic"];
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.profilepic);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply your reply solved my problem :) thanks alots once again

Comment: Matthias, the last part of your answer where you ask to remove the monster of a code. I don't understand how that's a causing a problem. Please help me understand since I'm doing something similar.